# Is it "evaluated as" or "evaluated to be"?

Tags: prepositions

For example, when we write programming code or math formula, would we say

If `obj` is `foo.bar`, then would we say

```
fn(foo.bar)
```

is first evaluated **as** `fn(obj)` (and then `fn` is invoked), or should we say it is first evaluated **to be** `fn(obj)`?

Likewise, if it is

```
fn(1 + 8)
```

would we say it is first evaluated **as** `fn(9)`, or should we say it is first evaluated **to be** `fn(9)`?

Is it very similar to the case of "we consider him to be correct", vs "we consider him as a father, not as a king" (we examine him thinking of him as a father, not as a king)?

Comment: In *X is evaluated **to be** Y*, the second term *(**Y**)* can *only* be the actual ***output*** of the evaluation exercise  (so it would normally be ***a number*** or something similar; the answer to the equation). But although the ***Y*** in *X is evaluated **as** Y* ***can*** be the same, that version can be used where there's a ***different*** relationship. For example, *The formula was evaluated **as an integer equation*** (all values were converted from floating point to integer before any further mathematical evaluation).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Could this be made an answer?  I'm going through some of the unanswered questions list.

Comment: No, it couldn't. My comment simply points out one relatively uncommon context where *X is evaluated **as** Y* and *X is evaluated **to be** Y* are not completely equivalent and interchangeable. Arguably that distinction isn't even *relevant* to the OP's problem here.

Comment: I am now also thinking "`fn(1 + 8)` is first evaluated to `fn(9)`" sounds ok too

Comment: "As" is best. But you should think about what you are trying to describe more precisely. Do you mean to say that something is being evaluated?

Answer (score 1):

It is not literally `fn(obj)` or `fn(9)`, it is literally `fn(foo.bar)` or `fn(1 + 8)`.  Hence, *to be* is not correct.  The intermediate step is performed, and then `fn(foo.bar)` is evaluated *as* (meaning, "as if it was") `fn(obj)`, and `fn(1 + 8)` is evaluated *as* `fn(9)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would put it this way:

- In the code `square_root(my_circle.get_area())` the computer first calculates `my_circle.get_area()`. Secondly, the computer calculates the square root of the result found in the first step.
- In the code `sqrt(1 + 8)`, we first compute `1+8`. After that, we pass the result from `1 + 8` into the `sqrt` function.

Comment: Yes, @Samuel Muldoon, that would have been a clearer phrasing. But it’s not the phrasing that the OP is puzzling over.

Answer (score 0):

> If `obj` is `foo.bar`, then would we say
>
> ```
> fn(foo.bar)
> ```
>
> is first evaluated **as** `fn(obj)` (and then `fn` is invoked), or should we say it is first evaluated **to be** `fn(obj)`?

We don't generally say either of those things, for two reasons:

1. To "evaluate" an expression normally means to *fully* evaluate it; so we would say that we evaluate `foo.bar` first, but not that we evaluate `fn(foo.bar)` to some intermediate expression.

   - There is such a thing as "partial evaluation", but it doesn't quite fit in your context, because it implies that the rest of the evaluation isn't happening until later (or at all); for example, a compiler might partially evaluate an expression at compile-time, leaving the rest of the evaluation for run-time.
2. For whatever reason, although we say that we "evaluate" an expression, and although we say that an expression "evaluates to" some value, we don't combine those two frames into one big "evaluate [expression] to [value]" — nor "evaluate [expression] as [value]", nor "evaluate [expression] to be [value]". Instead, we have to say something like "evaluate [expression], giving [value]".

So in your case, I would suggest something like this:

> In `fn(foo.bar)`, `foo.bar` [is evaluated first, giving](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is+evaluated+first+giving%22&tbm=bks) `obj`, then `fn` is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve only written code documentation in a practical environment and never in an academic setting, so there may be standards and practices that I don’t know about. If I were documenting my own code, then between,

```
1) If obj is foo.bar, then fn(obj) is evaluated as fn(foo.bar) before fn is invoked.
2) If obj is foo.bar, then fn(obj) is evaluated to be fn(foo.bar) before fn is invoked.
```

Example 1 is best because of the presence of a continuing process. *To be* is definitive; *as* is explanative. Using *as* makes the documentation more precise. The sentence is explaining the condition of the circumstances based on the values of the variables, not describing something that has been determined. The variables in question have not changed their original value.
In contrast,

```
1) fn(1+8) is evaluated as fn(9) [when used for processing].
2) [After processing] fn(1+8) is evaluated to be fn(9).
```

As a stand alone sentence, Example 2 works best as a description of the outcome of a process. The things in brackets are used to provide a context where either could work well.

This reasoning is consistent with the analogy asked about in the question.

```
A) We consider him to be correct. 
B) We consider him as a father, not as a king.
```

However, *We consider him to be a father, not (to be) a king* is absolutely a perfectly good sentence. It just offers a very different premise than the alternative in sentence B above.

The main point to take away from this examination is that: *To be* defines; *as* explains. What you want to say and where you want to say it are what determine which are the best tools to use.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking purely to the English language and not within the context of code, "evaluated as" seems most proper in my opinion but I can't say there's an exactly "correct" answer here. Either would be intelligible.

**TLDR** I would go with **as**